# Damaged laptop power plug?

Tags: laptop-repair, ac-adapter

Should I be worried about a damaged computer plug? My parents (or someone) knocked it over today. I notice it is no longer straight.

There seems like a little tear in the rubber from the fall. I'm mostly worried about how straight it is. It fell on the left side so this part took the most damage. The laptop itself looks completely fine.

Should I be worried about anything? Are there any articles that might interest me?

[image]

Answer (score 8):

It isn't dangerous per se, but further stress can damage it to the point where the wires break or come loose. It will probably need replacement eventually, but there's no urgency unless it already doesn't work.

Answer (score 4):

It wouldn't hurt to wrap in electrical tape, but it's not necessary.

Answer (score 2):

You should have no worries at all, if it works.

Electrically it is safe for your use as the laptop power is *at most* 24V (more likely much less, often 12V).
There is a small chance that a short could damage your laptop but it's very unlikely.

(This is from someone who has broken and repaired his laptop plugs)

Comment: 19V is quite common, in order to minimize losses when reducing the voltage.

Comment: In any case a safe voltage to work with.